# Use of slice command with split command?

Tags: python, split, slice

```
fh=open('asd.txt')
data=fh.read()
fh.close()

name=data.split('\n')[0][1:]
seq=''.join(data.split('\n')[1:])
print name
print seq
```

In this code, the 3rd line means "take only first line with first character removed" while the 4th line means "leave the first line and join the next remaining lines".
I cannot get the logic of these two lines.
Can anyone explain me how these two slice operators ([0][1:]) are used together?
Thanx

**Edited**: renamed `file` variable (which is a keyword, too) to `data`.

Comment: Don't use `file` as a variable.  It's the name of a built-in function.

Comment: Don't apologize.  Fix your example code.

Comment: any reason why you're not using `readlines()`? is just like `f.read().split('\n')`, but way better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of it like this: `file.split('\n')` gives you a list of strings. So the first indexing operation, `[0]`, gives you the first string in the list. Now, that string itself is a "list" of characters, so you can then do `[1:]` to get every character after the first. It's just like starting with a two-dimensional list (a list of lists) and indexing it twice.

Comment: The first set of square brackets isn't a slice operation -- it's an indexing operation. For a slice operation, the colon must be present (e.g. [:]).

Answer (score 4):

When confused by a complex expression, do it it steps.

```
>>> data.split('\n')[0][1:]

>>> data
>>> data.split('\n')
>>> data.split('\n')[0]
>>> data.split('\n')[0][1:]
```

That should help.

Comment: It's a technique I use almost daily to see what's going on in code. I think it has value for experts as well as beginners.

Comment: Yes. Just that experts will all know it, but forget to spell it out to beginners, because it feels too trivial to them ...

Answer (score 1):

lets do it by steps, (I think I know what name and seq is):

```
>>> file = ">Protein kinase\nADVTDADTSCVIN\nASHRGDTYERPLK"   <- that's what you get reading your (fasta) file 
>>> lines = file.split('\n')            <- make a list of lines
>>> line_0 = lines[0]                   <- take first line (line numbers start at 0)
>>> name = line_0[1:]                   <- give me line items [x:y] (from x to y)
>>> name
'Protein kinase'
>>> 
>>> file = ">Protein kinase\nADVTDADTSCVIN\nASHRGDTYERPLK"
>>> lines = file.split('\n')
>>> seqs = lines[1:]                    <- gime lines [x:y] (from x to y) 
>>> seq = ''.join(seqs)
>>> seq
'ADVTDADTSCVINASHRGDTYERPLK'
>>>
```

in slice [x:y], x is included, y is not included. When you want to arrive to the end of the list just do not indicate y -> [x:] (from item of index x to the end)

Answer (score 0):

Each set of [] just operates on the list that `split` returns, and the resulting
list or string then used without assigning it to another variable first.

Break down the third line like this:

```
lines = file.split('\n')
first_line = lines[0]
name = first_line[1:]
```

Break down the fourth line like this:

```
lines = file.split('\n')
all_but_first_line = lines[1:]
seq = ''.join(all_but_first_line)
```

Answer (score 0):

take this as an example

```
myl = [["hello","world","of","python"],["python","is","good"]]
```

so here myl is a `list of list`. So, `myl[0]` means first element of list which is equal  to `['hello', 'world', 'of', 'python']` but when you use `myl[0][1:]` it means selecting first element from list which is represented by `myl[0]` and than from the resulting list(myl[0]) select every element except first one(myl[0][1:]). So output = `['world', 'of', 'python']`